# Open links in standalone dedicated application

Tags: applications, multitasking

Im not sure how to word the question exactly but I will try and describe what I mean.

If im on a website, email or any app and there is a link that can be opened in a certain app, For example, clicking a youtube link, instagram link, pintrest etc it "opens" that app. But when I hit the multitasking button to look back on the site/email/source of the link, I find that the app is actually "inside" the source. For example, even though its opened the youtube app, when you click on the multitasking button it actually shows up as chrome (im not talking about it loading the youtube website).

Can it be set so it physically opens that respective app rather than "virtualising it" inside the source app?

I know this may sound very confusing...if so let me know ill try again or maybe do a video of what I mean...

Comment: I think that this is probably a choice left up to the developer of the app.  I am not aware of a way for the user to change it.

Comment: @MrZander Just want to check if you understand / im clear enough as its a bit of a werid thing... :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want apps that are opened from within another app to open in a sort of "standalone" mode instead of inside of the originating app.

I don't think it is the users choice, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. Any ideas why it is the way it is?

Comment: It allows the developer to have more control over the flow of the app.  Some developers may want you to return to their app once you are done.